# Ruby on Rails Authentication Devise or Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

hi people i m new to ruby on rails i m looking for authentication solution for my app and i came across Devise and Authlogic so my question is which one to choose?
my requirements
1.save time
2.highly customziable
3.easy to understand
4.easy to debug

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

**Please visit the link below and understand authentication from scratch.**

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

**Pros:**
*1. Very easy to understand, as a beginner.

2. Highly customizable.

3. Get an extreme handle of what is going on.

4. Good riddance from complex code.

5. Its written by you.*

**Cons:**
*1. Its written by you.*

Thanks.